# how to retrieve open file handle count for a pid via shell script

Tags: shell, count, pid, ls, filehandle

I am trying to retreive open file handle count for a particular PID in a variable via shell script and displaying the same.It is not showing the correct count.  Can someone please advise?

pid=$(ps -ef | grep 'instance="AC"' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
  f_count=$(ls /proc/$'{pid}' | wc -l) 
 **Expected output:**

=============
When executed in command line , it shows 
ps -ef | grep 'service_instance="AC"' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' 
25939

ls /proc/25939/fd | wc -l 
98

 
**Actual Output:**

f_count= 0

Appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: Your script is not looking in the `fd` subdirectory.

Comment: Also remember you need to be root to peek into the `fd` subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

##### Suggesting to replace:

```
pid=$(ps -ef | grep 'instance="AC"' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

With:

```
pid=$(pgrep -f 'instance="AC"')
```

Notice that `pid` takes the first matched process.

If there are more than one matched process `pgrep` returns multiple lines.

##### Suggesting to replace:

```
f_count=$(ls /proc/$'{pid}' | wc -l)
```

with

```
f_count=$(ls /proc/${pid}/fd | wc -l)
```

##### Or all together in one line

```
f_count=$(ls /proc/$(pgrep -f 'instance="AC"')/fd | wc -l)
```